# Autofilter to copy & paste multiple unique values

Tags: excel, vba, excel-tables

I'm trying to filter an Excel Table using VBA for unqiue values.
I first filter for a specific date, then I try to obtain unique values in columns `L`, `H` and `Q`.
My approach detailed below works properly only for column L. When I copy and paste unique values of columns H and Q, it does not take the filter values from those column, but rather all of the unfiltered values in those columns. 
Any pointer will be appreciated.

```
  With ActiveSheet.Range("Reconcile_Data")
        .AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria2:=Array(2, Format(var1(i, 1), "yyyy-mm-dd")), Operator:=xlFilterValues
        Range("L:L").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Resize(, 1).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Sheets("Uniques").Range("B1"), Unique:=True
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.Range("Reconcile_Data")
        .AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria2:=Array(2, Format(var1(i, 1), "yyyy-mm-dd")), Operator:=xlFilterValues
        Range("H:H").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Resize(, 1).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Sheets("Uniques").Range("C1"), Unique:=True
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.Range("Reconcile_Data")
        .AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria2:=Array(2, Format(var1(i, 1), "yyyy-mm-dd")), Operator:=xlFilterValues
        Range("Q:Q").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Resize(, 1).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Sheets("Uniques").Range("D1"), Unique:=True
    End With
```

Comment: With `ActiveSheet.Range("Reconcile_Data").AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria2:=Array(2, Format(var1(i, 1), "yyyy-mm-dd")), Operator:=xlFilterValues` on the 3 autofilters, you are filtering always the same range with the same field, same criteria and same operator, so how are you thinking that you will get different result? You should change the Range if you are looking for a different filter.

Comment: For each of the 3 autofilters, I first filter on field 9 and then I copy `Range(L:L)` or `Range(H:H)` or `Range(Q:Q)`... In each of the 3 filters, I want to first filter Field 9 for the same date and then take the respective unique values of those 3 columns `L, H and Q`